# Passing Errors Types into a Custom Error Handling Class, Python

Tags: python, error-handling

Being a Python novice, I resolve problems in interesting ways. This being one of them.

I'm wanting to pass Error messages into a Error Handling script (a Class), so I can customise the error message. For example, when 'FileNotFoundError' is raised, I want to display/send a message like 'Cant find xxx file, check yyy directory.'. Or 'ConnectionResetError', message ... 'Database connection restarted'.. and so on (about 15 different messages).

So, when an Exception is raised, I am passing the error:

```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
      try:
         do stuff...

       except Exception as e:
           ErrorHandlingClass.ErrorMessageHandler(e)
```

to

```
class ErrorMessageHandler:

     def __init__(self, error):
         err_type = str(type(error)) # obviously this is dumb
         err_type = (err_type[8:-2])

        if err_type == 'FileNotFoundError':
            print("Can not reach 'jconfig.json': {}".format(error))
```

Firstly, how to capture e.g. 'FileNotFoundError' without pulling out of a string.

Secondly, what the professional way?

Thirdly, since I need a bunch of if/elif to generate the unique message, why bother with a special Class, just put e.g. Except FileNotFoundError as e... with unique message, and put under 'main', and do 20 times, for each Error type raised? Then main becomes messy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly**, exceptions are instances of the Exception base class, and can be used as exceptions… so in your handler, you could:

```
def __init__(self, error):
    try:
        raise error 
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Can not reach 'jconfig.json': {}".format(error)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

If you insist on using if statements then maybe you can use `isinstance(obj, class)` instead of string comparison. So in your case `if isinstance(error, FileNotFoundError): ...`.

**Secondly**, this is alright if you want to centralize error handling. That really depends on your code. I don’t like this way because control is still in the main function and it is unclear what will happen after the handler finished handling. Will you `exit(error_code_bigger_than_zero)` or exit(0). Would you `raise e` to get the Python error trace back for debugging or do you want to end clean?

**Thirdly**. In Python it is better to create small functions that does one thing and does it good. I don’t think there should be anything in your main except:

```
if __name__ == “__main__”:
    main()
```

Of course the function main() should be defined somewhere in the same or in another file.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the education. @MarkedAsDuplicate, Ill use **singledispatch** for a bunch if statements Im using elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> just put e.g. Except FileNotFoundError as e... with unique message, and put under 'main', and do 20 times, for each Error type raised? Then main becomes messy.

It's often considered a [code smell](https://wiki.c2.com/?SwitchStatementsSmell) to manage a long chain of if statements for different object types, in this case exceptions. The most common way to avoid this is through [single dispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). Use either `@singledispatch` or `@singledispatchmethod` (it works essentially the same as the first, except you use it for class methods) if your use case actually requires a class:

```py
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def handle(err):
    raise err  # pass on errors by default

@handle.register(FileNotFoundError)
def _(err):
    print('File not found!')  # do what you want here
```

For example:

```py
try:
    raise FileNotFoundError
except Exception as e:
    handle(e)  # prints 'File not found!'
```

PS: In your original code you do not have to convert the exception to a string to check its type, you may simply use `isinstance(error, FileNotFoundError)` to check if your exception object is of a specified exception class.